# Docker in AWS Elastic Beanstalk: executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy a multi-container Docker app on Elastic Beanstalk.

One of the containers is a Celery container and I have a `worker.sh` script which initiates the celery workers. The `Dockerrun.aws.json` for this container looks like:

```
{
  "name": "celery",
  "image": "python:2",
  "memory": 384,
  "user": "nobody",
  "command": ["worker.sh"],
  "essential": true,
  "links": [
    "redis"
  ],
  "mountPoints": [
    {
      "containerPath": "/app",
      "sourceVolume": "_"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"worker.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Please keep in mind that I have tried the command without brackets:

```
"command": "worker.sh",
```

but I got the same error message.

How can modify my Dockerrun.aws.json file to run this script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `"command": ["worker.sh"]`, you need to provide the `full path` of script `worker.sh`.

Like the example bellow, the wrong `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ADD worker.sh /root/
CMD ["worker.sh"]
```

If I `docker build -t worker-test .` and `docker run worker-test`, I'll get:

> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"worker.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"worker.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH".
>
> ERRO[0001] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled

But if I change the `Dockerfile` to:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ADD worker.sh /root/
CMD ["/root/worker.sh"]
```

and do it over again, I'll get the correct output. BTW, remember to add `executable` permission to the script.

Comment: I use the ``eb local run`` of Elastic Beanstalk to run it locally before I deploy it. I am using ``"command":["/mnt/c/Users/ilias/Documents/Projects/hub/worker.sh"]``, but I get ``no such file or directory``